# Creating an If function for the probabilities of the classes of images after using NetTrain

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, conditional

So I have 3 Classes the model can output after veiwing an image, at the moment it has a 70% accuracy, however this is not an issue as the plan is unless it's 85%+ sure on the Probability of the class it will be marked as unsure and we will go back to classify in manually

I think using an `If`or `:=` would work well just not sure how to extract the probabilies using `Net[*image*,"Probabilities"]`
To create this option

Comment: Can you be more clear about what logic you're wanting? Like, what's the condition the "if" needs to evaluate and what is the result when "true" and what is the result when "false".

Comment: so the net will classify the image into having 3 probabilities equalling how likely it is to be in each class. So for my example the classes are metal, plastic and other. Now most of the time it says 0.9->plasitc, 0.09->metal, and 0.01-> other. This shows the network is pretty sure it's plastic. however when it gets below a threshold that i want to set at 0.85. I want it to say the network is unsure and this is when i would check the image myself

Comment: So the "If" function should be true when no probabilities from the classifier are more than 0.85 and it should produce a new class where these results go into a class called unsure.

Comment: Okay, so are you sure you wanted a NetChain as opposed to a ClassifierFunction?

Comment: Yes I’m not sure the classify function Is smart enough to classify images that are of particles only 40 micro meters in diameter, therefore I’m using quite a complex neural network to classify these particles

Comment: This isn't really my area of expertise, but it's my understanding that once you've trained a net, then your inputs will produce an output. The net is just turning a crank and producing a result. If the result is wrong, it's wrong. The net doesn't "know" that it might be wrong and has no idea of accuracy. All you can do if you don't like the output is do more training. `ClassifierFunction` on the other hand can produce the degree of "fit" for each class (you ask it for "Probabilities").

Comment: Maybe what you can do is train a net that has an extra output for "unknown". Instead of 3 outputs, you have 4, and the first three are accurate to your desired threshold. The 4th is whatever gets left over.

Comment: Cheers for your help I'll come back to this post if I find an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i found an answer after coming back to my problem,
After recieving the probabilities from
`probs=net[*listOfImages*,"Probabilities"]`.(net is a pre trained neural network using `NetChain` & `NetTrain`)
You can create the thresholds you want with a simple list
`thresholds = {0.5, 0.75, 0.75}`.
Then use an `If` function to say if the these probabilties are less than these thresholds class them into their own class

> `predictedClasses = If[#[[1]] >= thresholds[[1]], "class1",  If[#[[2]] >= thresholds[[2]], "class2",  If[#[[3]] >= thresholds[[3]], "class3", "newClass"]]] & /@ probs`

One thing to add, the images that you put into the neural net function to get the probabilities these must be images that have no class already applied, so brand new images.